# GameMaker Studio mouse click event goes wrong?

Tags: mouseevent, game-maker

I have used Gamemaker Studio for several months, but still learning it. Today I meet trouble with the mouse click action:

I have 2 objects called button_1 and button_2. My main purpose is that when a player clicks on button_1, it will be replaced by button_2, then clicks on button_2, it will be replaced by button_1.

So I did like this:

button_1:
event: mouse "left button" -> destroy itself and create object button_2 at the same position

button_2:
event: mouse "left button" -> destroy itself and create object button_1 at the same position

However, when I click on the button_1, it show the button_1 immediately. I guess the problem is caused by the position because when I put 2 buttons far from each other, it's okay, but if they overlap, problem appears on the shared area.

Have you ever faced the similar problem? Any idea to fix it?

I am learning English, please forgive me and ask if my explanation is not clear. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the "Left Released" action instead of "Left button".

I found that the "Left button" action triggers three times at a time, so I prefer using the "Left Released" action, because it triggers only once.

Comment: In fact "left button" works as long as you keep button pressed, so as many times as there's room_speed per second. For example by default it's 30 steps per second, so this event happens every 0.03 of second. It takes you more time to click for sure, so it will be catched several times :)

To test it, just make a simple game, add in create variable "counter = 0", then in event "left button" set "counter ++;", then draw it as string on screen. Click on object and you notice, that usually it incarese more than one.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I thought that it works like you said, but hever checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouse_clear(button)` in the button, like

```
mouse_clear(mb_left);
instance_create(x, y, button_2);
instance_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did:

- button_1: event mouse left button -> destroy itself and create object button_2 at same position
- button_2: event mouse left button -> destroy itself and create object button_1 at same position

Your mistake:

- Event should be "Left Pressed", not left button

I also recommend:

- Create the new instance before you destroy the old one

Answer (score 0):

As mention by other you should use the "Left Released" event instead of "Left button".

Moreover you should check thaht you only have on instance of the same object at the same place in the room. I was having the same problem (multiple click event fired) and it was cause by 2 or more object stacked each trigerring an event.